# Need help combining all the results

Tags: python

I have a small challenge to finish, but I cannot figure out the last part. Need help from some python expert :)

from my code I can iterate the first part, but I cannot get the "combined" to work.

```
#!/bin/python3

sub_fee = 7 
ad_fee = 2 
vod_fee = 27.99 
def subscription_summary(months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand_purchases, account_number):

total_sub_fee = (sub_fee) * (months_subscribed)
total_ad_fee = (ad_fee) * (ad_free_months)
total_vod_fee = (vod_fee) * (video_on_demand_purchases)
account_total = total_sub_fee + total_ad_fee + total_vod_fee
print("Account", account_number, "made", "${:,.2f}".format(account_total), "total")
print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_sub_fee), "from monthly subscription fees")
print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_ad_fee), "from Ad-free upgrades")
print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_vod_fee), "from Video on Demand purchases")
print() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
print("Output")
print()
sub_lists = [[1,1,3],[2,0,0],[2,2,1]]
for i in range(0,3):
    account_number = i + 1
    this_sub = sub_lists[i]
    subscription_summary(this_sub[0],this_sub[1],this_sub[2], account_number)
```

How do I iterate the last part, need someone smarter than me to help me out. :)

Thanks all.

Comment: It would help to know what *get the "combined" to work* means.

Comment: Scott, if you run my code, its only print the first part. But these are not working> # Combined all accounts made $152.96 total
"># Premium content (Ad-free watching and Video on Demand) made $117.96 total
> # $92.97 was the most earned by any single account
> # The accounts that earned the most were: #1
> #"

Comment: The code you have posted does not work at all. You seem to have run together a bunch of lines.

Comment: khelwood, sorry its my first time posting on here, seem like the `code` bracket is not working for me, but i've modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub_fee = 7
ad_fee = 2
vod_fee = 27.99

super_total = 0

def subscription_summary(months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand_purchases, account_number):

    global super_total
    """
    Parameters:
      months_subscribed: How many months each account purchased.
      ad_free_months: How many months each account paid for ad free viewing.
      video_on_demand_purchases: How many Videos on Demand each account purchased.
    """
    # Write your code here
    total_sub_fee = (sub_fee) * (months_subscribed)
    total_ad_fee = (ad_fee) * (ad_free_months)
    total_vod_fee = (vod_fee) * (video_on_demand_purchases)
    account_total = total_sub_fee + total_ad_fee + total_vod_fee
    print("Account", account_number, "made", "${:,.2f}".format(account_total), "total")
    print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_sub_fee), "from monthly subscription fees")
    print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_ad_fee), "from Ad-free upgrades")
    print(">>> ", "${:,.2f}".format(total_vod_fee), "from Video on Demand purchases")
    print("\n")

    super_total += account_total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Welcome to the Ada+ Account Dashboard")
    print("\n")

    sub_lists = [[1,1,3],[2,0,0],[2,2,1]]
    for i in range(0,3):
        account_number = i + 1
        this_sub = sub_lists[i]
        subscription_summary(this_sub[0],this_sub[1],this_sub[2], account_number)

    print("super total : ",super_total)
```

Comment: x = round(super_total, 2)

Comment: thanks laticoda, i'll use this for `> # Combined all accounts made $152.96 total
> # Premium content (Ad-free watching and Video on Demand) made $117.96 total
> # $92.97 was the most earned by any single account
> # The accounts that earned the most were: #1`

Comment: how do I get the max() of the 3 "account" and display that account, wheather the max was from account1/2/3.